# How to integrate over the polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

How can I go from
 $$\rho(r_1)=2A^2\exp(-4\beta r_1^2)\int d\mathbf r_2 \exp(-4\beta r_2^2)\exp[(r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta)^{1/2}] \tag{1}$$
to
$$\rho(r_1)=(4\pi A^2/r_1)\exp(-4\beta r_1^2+r_1)\int_0^{\infty}dr_2 r_2\,\exp(-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)\{ (r_1+r_2-1)+(1-\lvert r_1-r_2 \rvert)\exp[\,\lvert r_1-r_2\rvert-(r_1+r_2)]\} \tag{2}$$

You can download the original paper which I'm trying to reproduce its results [here](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/PhysRevA.42.1178.pdf).

The above problem is about equations 17 and 18.

Comment: Statement of problem is too minimalistic. Lots of details missing. Sounds like homework. You probably won't get help here in the current form. Where are you stuck precisely ? Also change $exp$ to $\exp$

Comment: @dohmatob No, it's not a homework, I'm trying to reproduce the results of a paper. In fact I have included all details. I really don't know how to present the problem here? any idea?

Comment: Include the reference to the paper in your question.

Comment: @Christoph Done.

Comment: I think you are missing some boldfacing in the equations. In physics one usually writes $r$ for the magnitude of a vector $\mathbf r$. The first equation should be over the whole space with respect to $\mathbf r_2$ while the second integral is over $[0,\infty)$ with respect to $r_2$.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks a lot. You were right, I corrected it. However I still can't solve the problem.

Comment: Then please include the steps you already tried and show us where you get stuck.

Comment: @Christoph Dear Christoph I have no idea how to proceed, and for this reason I asked it here to get some hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to do
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)r_2^2\sin\theta_2\,d\phi_2\,d\theta_2\,dr_2$$
I am assuming that $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ so that $\vec r_1\cdot\vec r_2=r_1r_2\cos\theta$. Our first transformation is to rotate the $\vec r_2$ coordinate system so that the $z_2$-axis is parallel to $\vec r_1$. The only change visible in our integral is that now $\cos\theta=\cos\theta_2$ which makes the integral much simpler.

The $\phi_2$ integral is
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi_2=2\pi$$
If we let $u=r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta_2$ then $(r_1-r_2)^2\le u\le(r_1+r_2)^2$, $du=2r_1r_2\sin\theta_2d\theta_2$ and when $\theta_2=0$, $u=(r_1-r_2)^2=u_-$ and when $\theta_2=\pi$, $u=(r_1+r_2)^2=u_+$. The $\theta_2$ integral is
$$\begin{align}\int_{u_-}^{u_+}e^{\sqrt u}\frac{du}{2r_1r_2}&=\int_0^{\pi}e^{\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta_2}}\sin\theta_2\,d\theta_2\\
&=\frac1{r_1r_2}\int_{\sqrt{u_-}}^{\sqrt{u_+}}e^v\cdot v\,dv\\
&=\left.\frac1{r_1r_2}(v-1)e^v\right|_{\sqrt{u_-}}^{\sqrt{u_+}}\\
&=\frac1{r_1r_2}\left[(|r_1+r_2|-1)e^{|r_1+r_2|}-(|r_1-r_2|-1)e^{|r_1-r_2|}\right]\\
&=\frac{e^{r_1+r_2}}{r_1r_2}\left[r_1+r_2-1-(|r_1-r_2|-1)e^{|r_1-r_2|-r_1-r_2}\right]\end{align}$$
Where we have also used the substitution $u=v^2$ so that $du=2v\,dv$ and when $u=u_-=(r_1-r_2)^2$, $v=\sqrt{u_-}=|r_1-r_2|$ and when $u=u_+$, $v=\sqrt{u_+}=|r_1+r_2|=r_1+r_2$. So your result is
$$2\pi\frac{e^{r_1}}{r_1}\int_0^{\infty}r_2e^{r_2}\left[r_1+r_2-1-(|r_1-r_2|-1)e^{|r_1-r_2|-r_1-r_2}\right]dr_2$$
Seems to match the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help. I didn't understand how you change variables after introducing $u$ and $v$, can you include more details and explanation?

Comment: I had to [sleep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OTrgrw8X70) so I hoped you could fill in the blanks and fix typos, but now I have a little time to add explanation myself.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much.